# Projection of a matrix onto the spectral norm ball

Tags: matrices, optimization, convex-optimization, projection, spectral-norm

Given a matrix $X$ with at least one singular value greater than $1$,

$$\begin{array}{ll} \underset{Z}{\text{minimize}} & \langle X - Z, X - Z \rangle\\ \text{subject to} & \| Z \| := \max_i \sigma_i (Z) \le 1\end{array}$$

where $\langle A,B \rangle := \mathrm{tr}(AB^\top)$.

---

I'm tempted to just replace the singular values of $X$ that are greater than $1$ with exactly one, but I can't prove that that's correct.  It's certainly right for the equivalent vector case of projection onto the $\ell_\infty$-ball.

Answer (score 5):

$\def\tr{\operatorname{tr}}\def\sc#1#2{\langle#1,#2\rangle}\def\scc#1{\sc{#1}{#1}}$I'm not sure whether the transpose in the trace was supposed to imply that these are real matrices; I'll do it for complex matrices using $\sc AB= \tr(AB^*)$ and the result for real matrices will follow. I'll assume distinct non-zero singular values to simplify things; I think you can do the same thing for degenerate and zero singular values with a bit more attention to details.

You can use the singular value decompositions of the two matrices and show that the singular vectors must be the same; it then follows that the singular values of $Z$ are as you say. So let $X=U\Sigma V^*$ and $Z=S\Lambda T^*$ with $U$, $V$, $S$, $T$ unitary, $\Sigma$, $\Lambda$ diagonal and real, $\Sigma,\Lambda\ge0$ and $\Lambda\le1$. Then

$$
\begin{align}
\scc{X-Z}
&=\scc{U\Sigma V^*-S\Lambda T^*}
\\
&=
\scc{U\Sigma V^*}+\scc{S\Lambda T^*}-\sc{S\Lambda T^*}{U\Sigma V^*}-\sc{U\Sigma V^*}{S\Lambda T^*}
\\
&=
\tr U\Sigma V^*V\Sigma^* U^*+\tr S\Lambda T^*T\Lambda^* S^*-\tr S\Lambda T^*V\Sigma^* U^*-\tr U\Sigma V^*T\Lambda^* S^*
\\
&=
\tr\Sigma\Sigma^*+\tr \Lambda\Lambda^*-2\Re\tr S\Lambda T^*V\Sigma^* U^*\;.
\end{align}
$$

Let $M=U^*S$ and $N=T^*V$ (so $M$ and $N$ are unitary), let $M=\mathrm e^{\mathrm iH}$ and $N=\mathrm e^{\mathrm iK}$ with $H$ and $K$ Hermitian, and vary $H$ and $K$ in $\Re\tr M\Lambda N\Sigma^*$. For each free parameter in $H$ we get an equation of the form 
$\Re\tr\mathrm iP_{kl}M\Lambda N\Sigma^*=0$, where $P_{kl}$ is an elementary Hermitian matrix, and similarly $\Re\tr\mathrm iP_{kl}\Sigma^*M\Lambda N=0$ from varying $K$. Forming linear combinations of these and using the assumption that the singular values in $\Sigma$ are distinct and non-zero, we can deduce from $\Re\tr\mathrm i(P_{kl}\Sigma^*\pm\Sigma^*P_{kl})M\Lambda N=0$ that $M\Lambda N$ is real and diagonal. Then it follows from the uniqueness of the singular value decomposition that $M\Lambda N=\Lambda$, so $M$ and $N$ contain only phase factors, and thus $S=U$ and $T=V$ up to phase factors that cancel in $Z$. Then

$$
\scc{X-Z}
=\scc{U\Sigma V^*-U\Lambda V^*}=\scc{\Sigma-\Lambda}\;,
$$

and it's clear that this is minimized by your correct guess.