# Projection of a symmetric matrix onto the positive semidefinite (PSD) cone under the nuclear norm

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, convex-optimization, positive-semidefinite, nuclear-norm

> **Question:** Given a symmetric matrix, $S$, what is the solution to the optimization problem $$ \arg\min_{P \in \mathcal{S}_{\ge 0}} \| S - P \|_N $$ where $\| \cdot \|_N$ denotes the nuclear norm, i.e. the sum of the singular values, or equivalently in the case of a symmetric matrix, the sum of the absolute value of the eigenvalues? 
>  In other words, given a symmetric matrix $S$, what is the closest matrix $P \succeq 0$ in the positive semidefinite cone (denoted $\mathcal{S}_{\ge 0}$) *with respect to the **nuclear** norm*?

---

**Guess:** I would guess that the answer is the same as for the spectral norm and the Frobenius norm, provided that the nuclear norm is unitarily invariant (is it? I don't know, and I can't find a reference). Namely the answer in those cases is apparently:

$$ V \Lambda^+ V^\top $$

where $V \Lambda V^\top$ is the eigenvalue decomposition of $S$, and $V^+$ is the diagonal matrix that is the same as $\Lambda$ except that any negative entries have been replaced with zero.

The following argument is obviously wrong, but imagine we would have that for any symmetric matrix $R = U K U^\top$, after applying a rotation to get $\tilde{R} = V K V^\top$, we would still have that (in fantasy land) $||S - R||_N = ||S - \tilde{R}||_N$, then we could assume without loss of generality that $U = V = I$, and then so calculating the nuclear norm of the difference would reduce to finding the nuclear norm $|| \Lambda - K ||_N$. But this is easy, since it's just the sum of the absolute values of the diagonals, $\sum_i| \lambda_i - \kappa_i|$, and then the only way to minimize this (is the following claim actually true?), while ensuring that all of the $\kappa_i \ge 0$, is to take $\kappa_i = \max\{ \lambda_i , 0 \}$, i.e. $K = \Lambda^+$.

Of course the claim about taking $V=U=I$ without loss of generality is obviously wrong, since then there would be no unique minimizer/no unique solution to the optimization problem, but the PSD cone is convex and the nuclear norm is a convex function.

However, it would seem to suffice to be able to show that $$ || V \Lambda V^\top - V K V^\top||_N < || V \Lambda V^\top - U K U^\top||_N$$
for any $U$ orthogonal and $U \not=V$. So I guess two claims of questionable merit:

> **Claim 1:** The minimizer of $$ \min_{i, \kappa_i \ge 0} \sum_{i} | \lambda_i - \kappa_i | $$ is $\kappa_i = \max \{0, \lambda_i\}$ for all $i$.

> **Claim 2:** $$ || V \Lambda V^\top - V K V^\top||_N < || V \Lambda V^\top - U K U^\top||_N$$
> for any $U$ orthogonal and $U \not=V$. (And any diagonal matrix $K$.)

The following questions are all related but don't answer my question, because they either involve projection onto a set different than the PSD cone, or projection with respect to a distance different from that induced by the nuclear norm (or w.r.t. an unspecified distance). So this question does not seem to be a duplicate of any of these.

- [Orthogonal projection on nuclear-norm ball](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2980213)
- [How to project a symmetric matrix onto the cone of positive semidefinite (PSD) matrices?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/525367)
- [Find the matrix projection of a symmetric matrix onto the set of symmetric positive semi definite (PSD) matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2436094)
- [Matrix projection onto positive semidefinite cone with respect to the spectral norm](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2776803)
- [Projection of a matrix onto the spectral norm ball](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/69647)
- [Projection of a real symmetric matrix to the cone of positive semidefinite (PSD) matrices ($ \mathcal{S}_{+} $)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1581552)